# Programmatically moving spacebar scrolling control

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, scrollbar

On most browsers, the scrollbar scrolls the window by a full page. If there's a scrollable div on the page, clicking it gives it focus and the scrollbar controls paging of that inner div.

Is it possible to programmatically force the spacebar to scroll a particular inner div and not the window?

Calling `focus()` on a div doesn't seem to transfer scrollbar control to it. ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r51fto7m/))

This only needs to support Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you give the div a *tabindex* attribute..

```
<div id="container" tabindex="1"></div>
```

It can be any number, not just **1**.

Comment: Didn't consider `tabindex`. Thanks!

Comment: For sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one (works for me):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content" tabindex="0">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("content").focus();
</script>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#content {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue, red); 
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

My code differs from yours in these two aspects:

1. focus() on div with gradient - because you want to scroll IT, not it's parent
2. to be able to focus on div at all, you must set it's tabindex attribute - something like "-10019000" "-5" "-1" "-1" "0" "1" "5" "10019000".

You can read a more about tabindex here, it would take only 1-5 minutes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp